# Bluebird detection

Tags: node.js, bluebird

For a library that supports any promise library, yet wants to know when [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird) is specified, in which way should it verify for it? -

- that would be simple and reliable
- that would not likely break with later versions of [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird)

---

```
var promise = require('any-promise-library');

function isBluebird(lib) {
    // do the checks
}

console.log(isBluebird(promise));
```

Comment: For what you need that checking?

Comment: To use some special features of the library, obviously.

Comment: What **special features**? Some method? You can check is some special method exists

Comment: That's not a scalable approach. I'd rather know in advance, and then use a number of special methods, rather than providing method-specific checks everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

**_promise0** is internal value in BlueBird library and author of that library also uses that property to check if passed object is native promise or blueBird one.

```
var Blue = require("bluebird");
var promise = new Blue(function() {})

function isBluebird(obj) {
    try {
        return {}.hasOwnProperty.call(obj, "_promise0");
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(isBluebird(promise))
```

or, if you want to test library ...

```
var Blue = require("bluebird");

function isBluebird(promiseLibrary) {
    var promise = new promiseLibrary(function() {})

    try {
        return {}.hasOwnProperty.call(promise, "_promise0");
    } catch (e) {
        return false;
    }
}

console.log(isBluebird(Blue))
```

For future breaking changes - please be in contact with author - as internal method **[isAnyBluebirdPromise](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/src/thenables.js#L50)** is internal - it can be changed with or without any reason

Comment: That returns `false` for the latest Bluebird :) There is no property `_promise0` on the library's root level.

Comment: What you are passing to function? promise object?

Comment: I showed that from the very beginning - the library instance. And doesn't this `new promiseLibrary(function() {})` create a loose promise?

Comment: It is interesting - when JavaScript will release promise variable - as long as there is no pointer to `promise` variable. Always you can assign null to that variable in the try block …

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Bluebird (that is if you can require it)

This is a check that "aPromise" is the same (version of) bluebird as the one available to you:

```
function isBluebird(aPromise) { // aPromise is the class of Promise, not an instance
    var B;
    try { var B = require ('bluebird') } catch(e) {}
    if (!B) return false; // bluebird must be installed

    return aPromise.getNewLibraryCopy === B.getNewLibraryCopy
}
```

Currently this also works if aPromise is the result of getNewLibraryCopy. But that is not guaranteed.

If you want the result of getNewLibraryCopy to be seen as different, compare `aPromise.resolve === B.resolve`

If you want to test a promise instance, you can compare `aPromise.then === B.resolve().then`. But that only works for the unmodified Bluebird. Intances of a getNewLibraryCopy promise will be different.